# Open operator and below bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

It is true that any open surjective linear operator $T:E \longrightarrow F$ between normed spaces is below bounded?

Answer (score 0):

If below bounded means that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|A(x)\|>C\|x\|$. A surjective non injective map between finite dimensional vector spaces is not below bounded, for examples $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ is open and not below bounded.

Comment: Than you Tsemo Aristide. This  result  is true if suppose that T is injective.